# Created ojects are not shown through cmd django python

Tags: python, django

```
from sabin.models import Task
>>> Task.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> t=Task(title="dhiraj")
t=Task(title="dhiraj")
t.save()
```

error says when try to save

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table sabin_task has no column named title

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
return manager._insert(
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table sabin_task has no column named title

```
models.py file

    from django.db import models

    class Task(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Did you forget `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `save()`, it is a method, not an attribute.

```py
t=Task(title="dhiraj")
t.save()
```

Also, before this, you must run:

```
>py manage.py makemigrations
>py manage.py migrate
```

And also, to get all objects, it is `Task.objects.all()`