# Created objects are not save through cmd in django python

Tags: python, django

```
from sabin.models import Task
>>> Task.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> t=Task(title="dhiraj")
t=Task(title="dhiraj")
t.save()
```

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
  return self.title
```

Error says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
 return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table sabin_task has no column named title

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 726, in save
 self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 763, in save_base
  updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 868, in _save_table
   results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 906, in _do_insert
   return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
  return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1410, in execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
   return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
   return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
  return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
   raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 423, in execute
  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table sabin_task has no column named title
```

Comment: did you makemigrations and migrate the db?

Comment: i do both makemigrations and migrate

Comment: @Dhiraj Why are you asking the _same_ [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416698/created-ojects-are-not-shown-through-cmd-django-python) again? Instead of asking the same closed question again _edit_ your previous question and get it reopened. Try running both again, you need to run them _each_ time you change the models.